# How to prevent redefinition of classes in C++ with multiple source files?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a game. This game uses 'scenes', and I have a scenes.hpp and .cpp file.

scenes.hpp:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "../renderer/renderer.hpp"

#include various scenes

#include <string>

class sceneInfo {
public:
  bool dialogueFinished[200];
  size_t dialogueIndex[200];
};

class scenes {
public:
  void render(renderer &renderer, std::string &sceneName, playerInfo &info,
              sceneInfo &sceneInfo);
};
```

scenes.cpp:

```cpp
#include "scenes.hpp"

void scenes::render(renderer &renderer, std::string &sceneName,
                    playerInfo &info, sceneInfo &sceneInfo) {
  if (sceneName == "some name") {
    some name(renderer, sceneName, info, sceneInfo);
  } ... (same stuff)
}
```

Now, the thing is: every scene has a .cpp and .hpp file as well. To pass the sceneInfo to each scene, I need to include scenes.hpp, but that gives me these errors:

i. redefinition of 'sceneInfo'
ii. redefinition of 'scenes'

How do I fix this? Thank you!

After changing #pragma once to the more standard header guard, it gives me different errors.

```
[build] error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'sceneInfo'
```

I have no clue what this means; that's the whole error message.

An example of the scene file I include:
theBlackRoom.hpp:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "../../renderer/renderer.hpp"
#include "../player/player.hpp"
#include "../scenes.hpp"

#include <chrono>
#include <string>

void theBlackRoom(renderer &renderer, std::string &sceneName, playerInfo &info,
                  sceneInfo &sceneInfo);
```

Comment: That error means that you either forgot include guards in some header(s) or you are indeed redefining those classes. Since you didn't provide a [mre] it is impossible to say which one you got wrong

Comment: Maybe your compiler doesn't understand 'pragma once'. You need a standard include guard

Comment: You failed to include the *exact* error message.

Comment: Make sure that none of your files include a `.cpp` file. Make sure that you have proper header guards.

Comment: I do have header guards, as you can see in my example.

Comment: We can't really help until you investigate the problem further. There is too little information in the question to help without guessing.

Comment: You also include with a relative path (that's bad) and gloss over a bunch of includes. *Some of which might not be properly guarded.* <- That's what was being said, not that the single incomplete header you posted isn't guarded.

Comment: Your edit makes it clear that you have a circular dependency / circular include problem.  Almost certainly the problem is trying to "Include various scenes" before defining `sceneInfo` -- how do you expect those scenes to compile if their datatype isn't known yet.  The fix may be as simple as exchanging the order of those includes with the definition of `class sceneInfo`

Comment: I'm not familiar with VS, but that's an error summary. You have to look somewhere else to get the full error message. This is also why I'm **not** in the camp that starting with a full fledged IDE is better for beginners. There's too many tools and knobs that do need to be touched for any given project, making it not-beginner-friendly. For all the hassle that setting up a C++ environment can be, those are generally valuable lessons that need to be learned. My beginner set-up is a text editor and the CLI.

Comment: And what in the world does "every scene has a .cpp and .hpp file as well" mean? This sounds like a foundational issue.

Comment: @sweenish well uhm, every scene is a function you can call. The actual function is in the .cpp file, definition in .hpp file.

Comment: @BenVoigt https://pastebin.com/fFP7dLMd here's an example of one of the .hpp files. I've included the data type before defining the function which uses it.

Comment: Why does every scene have its own pair of files?

Comment: @avighnac: You can't `#include "scenes.hpp"` from `foobar.hpp` if `scenes.hpp` does `#include "foobar.hpp"`  The include guard breaks the circle by causing one of the includes to just be ignored.

Comment: @BenVoigt thank you so much, that fixed it! Everything compiles fine now. That was honestly such a huge overlook!

Comment: Your problem here is that "scenes.hpp" is trying to be responsible for two things at once -- the building blocks to create scenes, and also the complete list of scenes.  Those goals are at odds with each other, separate them into two different header files.  If every scene header file does `#include "scenetools.hpp"` where `sceneInfo` is defined, and then "scenes.hpp" includes the many scenes, all will be fine.

Comment: @sweenish I'm not using VS 2022. It's Visual Studio Code with CMake. Visual Studio itself is too clunky for my taste.

Comment: That's still not the full error text. I can't recall which tab you need to switch to off the top of my head, but the compiler's complete error text is available to you.

Comment: We still need a [mre]

Answer (score 1):

You use include guards

either by

```
#ifdef YOUR_INCLUDE_GAURD
#define YOUR_INCLUDE_GAURD

#endif
```

or via

```
#pragma once
```

pragma once is very common but not really standard.

Comment: I do have `#pragma once` in my .hpp file- it doesn't fix it. The .cpp files are compiled and linked into one executable, so I understand why the redefinition error occurs.

Comment: @avighnac: I'm pretty sure you don't understand, or you wouldn't have had to ask this question.  In particular, your continued reference to "multiple .cpp files linked into one executable" suggests to me that you might be talking about static data members of the classes having multiple definitions, and not the classes themselves.  But I can't tell because your entire question is your restatement/summary of what happened, which is only as good as your understanding of what's important.

Comment: @BenVoigt hmm, I'm confused~ what exactly is the problem then? And no, I'm 100% sure it's the redefinition of the class itself that's the problem.

Comment: @avighnac: Your edit creates a lot more clarity.  You are correct that the problem was multiple definitions of the class itself.  And "multiple .cpp files" was a red herring, because the compiler can't finish compiling even one of them.